# Permalink: postname EXCEPT for blog

Tags: permalinks, blog, blog-page

In order to refrain from possible duplicate URLs or conflicting URLs, I really want to use "postname" for a clean URL structure, EXCEPT for the blog ... for the blog and it's posts, I always want /blog/ to be apart of the URL. This makes total sense, and I don't quite understand why it doesn't function like this when you specifically select a Page to represent the blog.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/this-is-a-page/

http://www.mydomain.com/blog/
http://www.mydomain.com/blog/my-blog-post/
```

Comment: what establishes a post as being part of the blog versus a post that isn't?

Comment: well, 1) it's a post and 2) the fact that I have to select a specific page to represent the blog and it's posts should be reason enough to use that pages permalink for all blog posts...

Comment: ... That's the way WordPress is supposed to work if you use a specific page for the Blog and set up a different page as your Front Page. Is this how you have it set up? What permalink structure are you using?

Comment: Huh? I don't see the point of telling WP that the "blog" is on a certain page, yet the blog posts don't pull in the permalink from that page?

Comment: that's just the way it works. you can achieve what you're after via the permalink settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to accept that this is just a limit of WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

if your posts page is `/blog/`, then set your post permalinks to `/blog/%postname%/`

Comment: Yes, but this would make the entire site display `/blog/`, no?

Comment: no, just posts. pages don't use posts permalink structure.

Comment: Is there a way to target JUST the generic "post" type? I mean, what about custom post types? I don't want a custom post type to display with a permalink of "/blog/"

Comment: when you register post types, you have the option to set the `'with_front'` argument of `rewrite` to `false`.