# Change posts URL

Tags: posts, permalinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permalink: postname EXCEPT for blog](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56206/permalink-postname-except-for-blog)

I have relented converted my website to wordpress and I have used index.php as homepage and blog.php(template for blog posts), but when I create any new post it makes permalink like pages for example...

```
http://www.domain.com/post-name
```

instead of `http://www.domain.com/blog/post-1`

Can you please help how can I assign /blog for all blog posts. Thanks for help.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56208/4771

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom permalink structure and have it be `/blog/` whatever.

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks